# Create nested object(s) based on flat objects

Tags: c#, recursion, nested

I have this class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int level, string value)
    {
        this.Level = level;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public int Level { get; private set; }

    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();

    public Item Clone()
    {
        return (Item)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

I receive a list of 'Items' like this:

```
List<Item> input = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(1, "A"),
    new Item(1, "B"),
    new Item(1, "C"),

    new Item(1, "D"),
    new Item(2, "E"),
    new Item(2, "F"),

    new Item(2, "G"),
    new Item(3, "H"),
    new Item(3, "I"),
    new Item(1, "J"),
    new Item(1, "K"),
    new Item(2, "L"),
    new Item(3, "M"),
};
```

Now, I need a function that creates a nested 'Item'-list, based on the 'levels' (1, 2, 3, etc.).

Therefore, based on the above example, the descried result should be:

```
List<Item> descriedOutput = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(1, "A"),
    new Item(1, "B"),
    new Item(1, "C"),
    new Item(1, "D")
        { Items = { new Item(2, "E"), new Item(2, "F"), new Item(2, "G") { Items = { new Item(3, "H"), new Item(3, "I") } } } },
    new Item(1, "J"),
    new Item(1, "K")
        { Items = { new Item(2, "L") { Items = { new Item(3, "M") } } } },
};
```

Or, expressed in plain text, you would get:

```
- A
- B
- C
- D
-- E
-- F
-- G
--- H
--- I
- J
- K
-- L
--- M
```

I got stuck while trying to create a recursive function. Any ideas on how to construct such a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it using a recursive function:

1. Start with level 1
2. If the current input item is the same level, add it to the output
3. If the current input item has a bigger level, call the function again with the children of the last output (which is the parent).
4. If the current input item has a smaller level, go back one level and break the loop, otherwise future items will be missed.

```cs
private List<Item> GenerateOutput(List<Item> input)
{
    List<Item> output = new List<Item>();
    var index = 0;
    GenerateOutput(input, output, ref index);
    return output;
}

private void GenerateOutput(List<Item> input, List<Item> output, ref int index, int level = 1)
{
    while (index < input.Count)
    {
        if (input[index].Level == level) // Same level
        {
            output.Add(input[index]);
        }
        else if (input[index].Level > level) // Child
        {
            GenerateOutput(input, output[^1].Items, ref index, level + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            index--; // Go back one level
            break;
        }
        
        index++;
    }
}
```

To use it, simply call:

```cs
List<Item> output = GenerateOutput(input);
```

This will output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Haytam, this function is working great!

Answer (score 0):

`input` list contains tree nodes enumerated from top to bottom.

by looking at the flat structure we see, that top level braches start with number 1, sub-brunches with number 2.

```
List<Item> input = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(1, "A"),

    new Item(1, "B"),

    new Item(1, "C"),

    new Item(1, "D"),
    new Item(2, "E"),
    new Item(2, "F"),
    new Item(2, "G"),
    new Item(3, "H"),
    new Item(3, "I"),

    new Item(1, "J"),

    new Item(1, "K"),
    new Item(2, "L"),
    new Item(3, "M"),
};
```

we can find brach growing from each node by comparing levels of child nodes:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
{
    var root = input[i];

    for(int j = i + 1; j < input.Count; j++)
    {
        var node = input[j];

        // the level direct child is greater than parent's level by one
        if (node.Level == root.Level + 1)
            root.Items.Add(node);

        // no descendant can have level less than parent's level, so we found another branch
        else if (node.Level <= root.Level)
            break;
    }
}
```